# Iterate through a file with bash not working properly

Tags: bash

I have a list of gradle dependencies that I want to use to compare two files to see how they differ for each item in the list. The contents of the script is like this:

```
───────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
       │ File: list_of_dependencies
───────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1   │ :cdp:aggregatedheader:aggregatedheader-common
   2   │ :agility-ris-server:server:com.ris.server.queue.mgmt
   3   │ :agility-ris-server:common:com.ris.common
...
  77   │ org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.2
  78   │ org.slf4j:slf4j-api
  79   │ org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:2.5.1
───────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

So I wrote this script to iterate through the list:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dependency_list=$1

file_1=$2

file_2=$3

# Read in default values
while read -r dependency
do
  echo "dependency = '$dependency'"

  echo "${file_1}:"
  grep "'${dependency}'" "${file_1}"

  echo "${file_2}:"
  grep "${dependency}" "${file_2}"

  exit 0

done < "${dependency_list}"
```

Which I would call using:

`./compare_dependencies.sh list_of_dependencies build.gradle build.gradle.backup`

The output looks like this:

```
$ compare_dependencies.sh list_of_dependencies build.gradle build.gradle.backup
'ependency = ':cdp:aggregatedheader:aggregatedheader-common
build.gradle:
build.gradle.backup:
```

As you can see when the dependency gets printed, it added `'` at the beginning of the line. I'm guessing that it's because of the `:` is messing things up. How can I pass it as a literal rather than letting bash perform substitutions on the string.

Comment: The file has CRLF line endings, fix it with `dos2unix`.

Comment: Or you could use `while IFS=$IFS$'\r' read -r dependency` to get `read` to trim the carriage return itself. (Although you should still convert the file(s) with `dos2unix`, as this is probably not the only problem CRLF line endings will cause.)

Comment: Thanks @GordonDavisson using `while IFS=$IFS$'\r'` worked. @Barmar, I guess git-for-windows added the CRLF line endings when it cloned the repo. I'll try to keep that in mind for next time. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you adding single quotes to the pattern passed to `grep`?

Comment: @Craig If you're doing this under Windows, lots of things are going to use the DOS/Windows text file format. Translating back & forth may just be something you'll need to get used to.